# Word scrambled, brain scrambled, Ngram

Tags: google-ngram

What you are given is one large group of words scrambled together

**yasbehhmsirauonyeoetjdonfe!**

There are a total of *seven* words in this jumble of letters

Now here is the real hard challenge!

What you must do is recreate this Ngram.  This is a graph on how often these words or phrases have occurred in a corpus of books(7 words total) from 2000 - 2005.  [This](https://books.google.com/ngrams/info) link shows you how to use the Ngram.

What an Ngram does in English: The Ngram charts how often words or phrases are used in a variety of books.

[image]  
 Edits have been made to the pictures to hide the answers.

This is the percentages the words appear at the end of the Ngram in 2005  
[image]  
Text version

0.6610909011%  
0.2998929238%  
0.2840928733%  
0.1548114233%  
0.1425059047%  
0.0613774173%  
0.0000081492%

At the top of the Ngram you are given a few options.

1. You decide what year you would like to reproduce.  For this Ngram we will use *2000 - 2005*
2. You decide what language you would like to use.  For this Ngram plain *English* will be used
3. Next you have the option of smoothing.  This will be set to *0*.

Here's what it'll look like
[image]

4. Last you have the option of case-sensitivity. This should be left unchecked.
   [image]

Here is an example of what you need to do.

Find a word in the scramble of letters.

**yasb**ehh**ms**irauony**e**oetjdonfe! *bold letters spell Embassy*

Paste the word in the Ngram text box. (Where in the picture it says "Unscrambled words go here").
See if the percentage matches one of the percentages above

Sadly, this is an example so it doesn't

[image]  
 Text version:  
0.0003612526%

Once you have all the words that have the correct percentages, put them all together and you have beaten the time consuming game!  Make your answer a link to the [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams) website

Overall goal: You need to find the words that are used the same amount as the percentages, within the scramble of words.

Note 1: One word will have a ! at the end

Note 2: The words will sound somewhat like a sentence if read from top to bottom, but you may have to imagine a bit and add some commas.

Comment: In the 27 letters given, each letter is used only a single time for a single word, I asume? (Still this would maybe be more fun if you at least give the lengths or legth-limits of words (Or a 'category' they all belong to etc.). Otherwise, the search space is just too big to be fun.)

Comment: You mentioned that the "case-insensitive" checkbox should be kept off. Does this mean all the words to be found are lower-case only? (Because the string is lower-case letters only).

Comment: The goal is to get the 2005 percentages, right? You should clarify this, as your example shows the 2004 percentage.

Comment: If you are searching for the words, you should set the years from 2005 to 2006, this way you'll see only the 2005 values if you hover the graph.

Comment: @Christoph, that is a very good poin, I actually didn't catch that. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: @BmyGuest, thanks I'll keep that in mind for the next on, but Christoph solved it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The words are

> 0.6610909011% - for
>  0.2998929238% - you
>  0.2840928733% - this
>  0.1548114233% - has
>  0.1425059047% - been
>  0.0613774173% - made
>  0.0000081492% - enjoy!

The ngram:

> [image]

How I found them:

> After a few random tries I noticed that the words had to be quite common, so I started with [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English), which gave me the first three words. After that I did some educated guessing with the help of [this anagram solver](http://wordsmith.org/anagram/advanced.html). The more words I found, the easier it got.